# Events not showing when Visual studio is not open

Tags: fullcalendar

I have created a fully functional calendar with events all displaying in an MVC web application. The events are all displaying correctly when my visuall studio project is open and i have Debuged the project. However when I close my visual studio project the events don't display anymore.

Is this a problem with the Javascript Plugin, Because a call is made and all the events are returned on this link. 
?start=2016-02-01&end=2016-03-14&_=1454571912445

Why are the events not showing when the project is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, No idea why visual studio had any effect on it. But the problem was that i had an test Event in JSON format on the Fullcalendar script. I just copied out the test event and it all worked fine

/*var JSON = [
  {
       "title": "Demo event",
       "start": "2016-02-11 10:20:00",
       "end": "2016-02-13 11:00:00",
       "note": "My new note",
       "allDay": false,
       "className":"event-approved"
   }
];*/

$(document).ready(function ()
{

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    //defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    editable: false,
    events: "/getevents/",
    firstDay: 1,
    height: 850,


    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view)
    {
        $('#myModal').modal('show')
        $('#title').text(calEvent.title)
        $('#start').text(calEvent.start)
        $('#note').text(calEvent.Note)
        $('#end').text(calEvent.end)
        $('#approvalStatus').text(calEvent.approvalStatus)
        console.log(calEvent);
    },

});
```

});